# Why can't AES be used as a part of a hashing algorithm?

Tags: encryption, hash, cryptography

Could AES be used as part of a hashing algorithm. If the input data was used as the key. A possible example could be below. Does this work and is it secure?

```
static byte[] AesOneWayEncrypt(byte[] input)
    {
        using (Aes aes = Aes.Create())
        {
            aes.Key = keccak.ComputeBytes(input).GetBytes();
            Array.Copy(keccak.ComputeBytes(aes.Key).GetBytes(), aes.IV, 16);

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor();

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cs.Write(data);
                }
                encryptedData.AddRange(ms.ToArray());
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what `data` is here (in `cs.Write(data)`). Is that a fixed string of some kind? If you already have Keccak available, why are you trying to turn that into another hashing function with AES? What's is AES achieving here that Keccak doesn't already achieve?

Comment: Secure hash algorithms don't use a key. I you are looking for a MAC based on Keccak, try the KMAC algorithm or (less efficient) use HMAC with Keccak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but it's a compromise on both performance and security. Requirements from good hash function aren't the same as from a good encryption algorithm. For example, read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Hash_functions_based_on_block_ciphers